# ASP.NET MVC One-to-One Relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dbcontext, one-to-one, database-relations

After i finished my SimpleMembership Step on my Application, there is another problem...

```
namespace Korbball.Models
{
    public class GamesContext : DbContext
    {
        public GamesContext()
            : base("KorbballDBContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Games> Games { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teams> Teams { get; set; }
    }
    public class Games
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int GameId { get; set; }
        public int TeamA { get; set; }
        public int TeamB { get; set; }
        public int ResultA { get; set; }
        public int ResultB { get; set; }
        public int League { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public Boolean Finished { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teams
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My target is, to create Games with Results etc.
The TeamA & TeamB column shoukd be the TeamID from the Teams Table.

Whats steps i have to do to set the correct relationship.

Additional Informations:

Games Table ->

```
GamesID = 1
TeamA = 1
TeamB = 2
ResultA = 10
ResultB = 8
```

Teams Table ->

```
TeamId = 1 
TeamName = "Manchester"

TeamId = 2
TeamName = "Zurich"
```

On the view ->

```
Manchester 10 : 8 Zurich
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i changed the code into this:

```
public class GamesContext : DbContext
{
    public GamesContext()
        : base("KorbballDBContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Games> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teams> Teams { get; set; }
}
public class Games
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public virtual Teams TeamA { get; set; }
    public virtual Teams TeamB { get; set; }
    public int ResultA { get; set; }
    public int ResultB { get; set; }
    public int League { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean Finished { get; set; }
}

public class Teams
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
public class GamesController : Controller
{
    GamesContext db = new GamesContext();

    //
    // GET: /Games/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var games = from game in db.Games
                    join teama in db.Teams on game.TeamA.TeamId equals teama.TeamId
                    join teamb in db.Teams on game.TeamB.TeamId equals teamb.TeamId
                    select game;

        return View(games.ToList());
    }
}

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamA.TeamName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResultA)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResultB)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamB.TeamName)
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to do, but if you create it like this, with the `public virtual Team`, the entity framework will automatically take care of the mapping for you and you can just access these "navigation properties" like normal objects.

```
namespace Korbball.Models
{
    public class GamesContext : DbContext
    {
        public GamesContext()
            : base("KorbballDBContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Games> Games { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teams> Teams { get; set; }
    }
    public class Games
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int GameId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team TeamA { get; set; }
        public virtual Team TeamB { get; set; }
        public int ResultA { get; set; }
        public int ResultB { get; set; }
        public int League { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public Boolean Finished { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teams
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Ok, this is how I usually do this:
I create **virtual** fields for all navigation properties, which in your case would only be the Teams as I already pointed out.

Then, when you create the Teams (which have to be there before the game can exist), you just add them like:

```
var teamM = new Team(){TeamName = "Manchester"};
var teamZ = new Team(){TeamName = "Zurich"};

// 'db' is your DbContext

db.Teams.Add(teamM);
db.Teams.Add(teamZ);
// This could also happen through some user form or something.

db.SaveChanges();  
// this is important, because only after you've safed entities to you db,
// the [DatabaseGenerated] key will be set.

var game1 = new Game();
game1.ResultA = 10;
game1.ResultB = 8;

//etc.

game1.TeamA = teamM;   
game1.TeamB = teamZ;
// we still have those from up when we created an db.SaveChanges'd them

// now save everything and the Entity Framework will take care of all the relationships

db.SaveChanges();
```

If you have already saved the Teams and they exist in you database, you can do something like:

```
var team1 = db.Teams.Find(0);  // 0 beeing the [Key]  => Manchester
// or
var team2 = db.Teams.Where(m => m.Name.Contains("Zu");  //  => Zurich

// Now do the same thing with game1:

game1.TeamA = team1;
game1.TeamB = team2;

db.SaveChanges();
```

I hope this is what you want to know.

If this won't work, you need to take a look at some **up-to-date** tutorials about entity framework code first. Lots of things can go wrong with all the initialization / database creation.

Comment: I've tried some variants with this virtual key, but it doesn't work or i don't know how to give the data correctly from controller to model. But many thanks for your answer! i changed something on the question to give more details

Comment: Have you tried the things I posted in my edit? It's very important to declare navigation properties "virtual".

Comment: my new solution is posted on a new answer.